# How can I count the cells in a range whose string values meet certain conditions after manipulating them in some way?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm well aware of `COUNTIF`. But suppose cells under Column A have string values that could be separated by certain characters, like `apple,tree,car` or even a new-line character like so:

```
trumpet
flute
drums
```

How can I write a function that counts only the cells which, after splitting their content by some delimiter (a comma or new-line character in this case), contain a certain number of substrings?

For example, if my cells are as follows:

A1

```
fish-bear-cat
```

A2

```
donkey-lion
```

A3

```
horse-tiger-whale
```

then something like `=COUNTIF( COUNTA( SPLIT( A1:A3, "-" ) ) = 3 )` would return 2.

Answer (score 2):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(3=1+LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"-",)))
```

- LEN()-LEN(SUBSTITUTE()) to provide number of delimiters
- SUMPRODUCT to sumup TRUEs,If 3=Number of delimiters+1

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3, "-", TEXT(,)))=3-1))
```

Note that Excel's SUMPRODUCT requires a double unary (e.g. `--`) to convert the boolean result to a numerical count.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the answer. But using LEN() over a range gives me an error. If I use LEN on a single cell, then it is alright.

Comment: @Manuel - That formula works, as does this for [tag:excel] `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3, "-", TEXT(,)))=C4-1))`